# modifying MB's General Update Pattern III to reposition text

Tags: d3.js

I would like to reuse the general update pattern III for a project and
want to know how to make the text labels line up better with the circle elements. My experiment is to attach circle elements and text to the "g", but I cannot place the text labels correctly.

Here is how I modified the block:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

text {
  font: bold 28px monospace;
}

.enter {
  fill: green;
}

.update {
  //fill: #333;
  fill: red;
}

.exit {
  //fill: brown;
  fill: blue;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="../d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

function randomData(){
               return d3.range(~~(Math.random()*50)+1).map(function(d,   i){return ~~(Math.random()*100);});
                }


var alphabet = "";
var numlist = [];
var randomEntry;
             for (i = 0; i< 2; i++) {
           randomEntry = randomData();
       numlist.push( randomEntry);
       }
var temp = numlist.toString();
var temp2 = temp.split('"');
alphabet = temp2.pop();
console.log("alphabet", alphabet);
var temp3  = alphabet.toString();
 console.log("temp3", temp3);
 console.log("temp3 type", typeof(temp3));

 var temp4 = alphabet.split(",");
 alphabet = temp4;
 console.log("alphabet", alphabet);


var width = 960,
height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(32," + (height / 2) + ")");

function update(data) {

  // DATA JOIN
  // Join new data with old elements, if any.
  var text = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(data, function(d) { return d; });

  var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data, function(d) { return d; });

  // UPDATE
  // Update old elements as needed.
  circles.attr("class", "update")
    .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("opacity", 0.3)
      .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return (Math.random(i))*100;})
      .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return (Math.random(i))*100;})
      .attr("transform", "translate(200," + (-100) + ")");

  text.attr("class", "update")
    .transition()
      .duration(750)
       .attr("x", function(d,i) { return (Math.random(i))*100; })
      .attr("y", function(d,i) { return (Math.random(i))*100; })
      .attr("transform", "translate(200," + (-100) + ")");


  // ENTER
  // Create new elements as needed.
  circles.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "enter")
      .attr("opacity", 0.3)
      .attr("r", 25)
      .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return (Math.random(i))*270;})
      .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return (Math.random(i))*270;})
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)

    .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("r", 30)
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);


  text.enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "enter")
      .attr("dy", ".25em")
       .attr("x", function(d) { return (Math.random(i))*100; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return (Math.random(i))*100; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
      .text(function(d) { return d; })
      .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);


  // EXIT
  // Remove old elements as needed.
  text.exit()
      .attr("class", "exit")
     .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("y", 60)
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
      .remove();

  circles.exit()
      .attr("class", "exit")
    .transition()
      .duration(750)

     .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
      .remove();
 }

// The initial display.
 update(alphabet);

// Grab a random sample of letters from the alphabet, in alphabetical     order.
   setInterval(function() {
     update(shuffle(alphabet)
     .slice(0, Math.floor(Math.random() * 26))
     .sort());
}, 1500);

// Shuffles the input array.
 function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;
  while (m) {
   i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
    t = array[m], array[m] = array[i], array[i] = t;
  }
  return array;
 }

 </script>
```

How can I change this so the text labels appear next to the circle elements?  Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: The first step would be to not use random positions. Make the positions determined by the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to making a random data for determining circle DOM's cx and cy of the circle:

```
  .attr("cy", function(d,i) { return (Math.random(i))*270;})
  .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return (Math.random(i))*270;})
```

In text DOM you make random points for determining x and y of text.

```
  .attr("x", function(d) { return (Math.random(i))*100; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return (Math.random(i))*100; })
```

So as a fix you can have a common data which will decide the x/y for text and cx/cy for circle.

BY making a function like this:

```
function randomData() {
  return (Math.random() * 500);//his generates a single random point
}


var alphabet = [];

function randomEntry() {
  var numlist = [];

  var randomEntry;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //generate 5 random coordinate
    //here first element willdecide the x and second element decide the y.
    numlist.push([randomData(), randomData()]);
  }
  //this will contain 5 coordinate points.
  return numlist;
}
```

Then set the 5 coordinates point data in the text and circel like this:

```
  var text = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data, function(d) {
      return d;
    });

  var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data, function(d) {
      return d;
    });
```

Then in the update

```
  circles.attr("class", "update")
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("opacity", 0.3)
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
      return d[0];//here d[0] is the x coordinate which determine the circle center x
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
      return d[1];//here d[1] is the y coordinate which determine the circle center y
    })

  text.attr("class", "update")
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return d[0];
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return d[1];
    })
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RHrpDGe4XkJukgNF9oWK?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Cyril, this helps a lot and points me in the right direction.

Comment: please accept it as answer if it helps...here is how it works http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235